# Copy a specific field of a file and paste it into another specific field of another existing file - lunx commands

Tags: linux, file, copy-paste

Good afternoon everyone, I have two files like these:

File 1

```
45.999 60.9999
70.000 23.0090
```

File 2

```
DATAFILE
pheno.txt
TRAITS
FIELDS_PASSED TO OUTPUT

WEIGHT(S)

RESIDUAL_VARIANCE

EFFECT
2 cross alpha
EFFECT
1 cross alpha
RANDOM
animal
FILE
pedigree.txt
SNP_FILE
snp_.txt
(CO)VARIANCES
```

and need to pass the values of file 1 for specific places of file 2 like this:

File 2

```
DATAFILE
pheno.txt
TRAITS
FIELDS_PASSED TO OUTPUT

WEIGHT(S)

RESIDUAL_VARIANCE
45.999
EFFECT
2 cross alpha
EFFECT
1 cross alpha
RANDOM
animal
FILE
pedigree.txt
SNP_FILE
snp_.txt
(CO)VARIANCES
23.0090
```

remembering, I want to keep the file 2, just add the file 1 values

Comment: Yes, you've got your work cut out for you. I recommend that you also improve your specification to identify corner-cases that are expected, and indicate how to handle unanticipated errors. After you have made an attempt to write your code and have a specific problem, post an actionable question including **your code**, small sample inputs, expected output given those inputs, and any error messages you are currently getting. Please read the FAQ before posting any more Qs. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set -- $(<file1)
sed -i "/RESIDUAL_VARIANCE/{n;c$1
};\${s/[0-9].*/$4/;t;a$4
}" file2
```

See also [`man sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed):

> **-i** edit files in place